# Objeto DateTime apenas com DIA,MES, HORA

Tags: c#

Preciso criar um objeto do tipo *DateTime* que contenha apenas **Dia**, **Mês** e **Hora**.
Pode até ter minutos e segundos mas não pode ter Ano.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, você pode criar seu próprio tipo - mas um DateTime sempre tem data e hora completas.Você pode sempre ignorar o ano - ou usar o ano atual:

```
DateTime data = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, mes, dia);
```

Para criar seu próprio tipo você pode fazer algo similar a isso:

```
  public struct MesDia : IEquatable<MesDia>
{
    private readonly DateTime data;

    public MesDia(int mes, int dia)
    {
        data = new DateTime(2018, mes, dia);
    }

    public MesDia AddDays(int dia)
    {
        DateTime added = data.AddDays(dia);
        return new MesDia(added.Month, added.Day);
    }

    public bool Equals(MesDia other)
    {
       //implementar;
    }
}
```